# React vite app successfully deploys on gh pages but routing gives 404

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, github-pages, vite

I'm trying to deploy a React vite JavaScript app on Github pages. I created a deploy.yml file and was able to successfully deploy the site but, the routing is giving me problems.

The app loads the splash page when I go to username.github.io/business/ (Not real url)
On the navbar there are 4 buttons home, menu, gallery and feedback. Whenever I click home it brings to me my own personal github site?? username.github.io, and the other links are 404.

My code is below

```
    return(
        <header id='main-header'>
            <a href='/'>
            <h3 id="business">Business</h3>
            </a>
            <nav ref={navRef}>
                <a href="/" className='link'>Home</a>
                <a href="/menu">Menu</a>
                <a href="/gallery">Gallery</a>
                <a href="/feedback">Feedback</a>
                <button className='nav-btn nav-close-btn' onClick={toggleNavBar}>
                    <FaTimes/>
                </button>
            </nav>
            <button className='nav-btn' onClick={toggleNavBar}>
                <FaBars/>
            </button>
        </header>
    );
```

In my navbar I have created the links to each page

```
function App() {
  return (
    <>
        <NavBar />
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<SplashPage />} />
            <Route path="/menu" element={<Menu />} />
            <Route path="/feedback" element={<Feedback />} />
            <Route path="/gallery" element={<Gallery />} />
          </Routes>
        <Footer />
      </>
  );
}
```

I also created the routing in App.jsx

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client'
import { HashRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
import App from './App'
import './index.css'

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <HashRouter basename='/business'>
    <App />
    </HashRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>,
)
```

This is the main.jsx file, I originally used browser router but other answers said HashRouter is better.

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  base: '/business/'
})
```

I made sure to add a base too

```
{
  "name": "business",
  "homepage": "https://github.com/username/business",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.7.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.9.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^18.0.27",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.10",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^3.1.0",
    "vite": "^4.1.0"
  }
}
```

This is my package.json

I've tried using HashRouter and adding /business to my a tags

example

```
 <a href="business/menu">Menu</a>
```

<Route path="/business/menu" element={} />

I also tried adding a home page in the package.json but that didn't work either.

Comment: `<Route path="/#/menu" element={<Menu />} />` should work, but you should switch to using `Link`

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the raw anchor tags in the first snippet are correct, they should be `Link` components with a `to` prop to a route path you are rendering. Using raw anchor tags will make a page request to the server and reload the page. You want to just handle navigating client-side.

Example:

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

...

return(
  <header id='main-header'>
    <Link to='/'>
      <h3 id="business">Business</h3>
    </Link>
    <nav ref={navRef}>
      <Link to="/" className='link'>Home</Link>
      <Link to="/menu">Menu</Link>
      <Link to="/gallery">Gallery</Link>
      <Link to="/feedback">Feedback</Link>
      <button
        type="button"
        className='nav-btn nav-close-btn'
        onClick={toggleNavBar}
      >
        <FaTimes />
      </button>
    </nav>
    <button
      type="button"
      className='nav-btn'
      onClick={toggleNavBar}
    >
      <FaBars />
    </button>
  </header>
);
```